# What are the step to the Reingold-Tilford algorithm and how might I program it?

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm, user-interface, tree

From the presentation: [Graphs and Trees](http://hci.stanford.edu/courses/cs448b/f09/lectures/CS448B-20091021-GraphsAndTrees.pdf) on page 3, there is a visual presentation of what takes place during the Reigngold-Tilford process; it also gives a vague summary to this algorithm before hand: `"...starts with bottom-up pass of the tree;
[finishes with] Top-down pass for assignment of final positions..."` I can achieve both directional passes through recursive means, and I know that the Y-value(s) are respective to each node's generation level, but I'm still lost as to how the X-coordinates are solved.

I did come across this project: [A Graph Tree Drawing Control for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29518/A-Graph-Tree-Drawing-Control-for-WPF) but there is so much code I had great difficulty locating what should be a simple 2-3 methods to define the X-values. (Also have no experience with WPF as well)

I have been searching and experimenting how to do this for several days now, so your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I found the articles listed in [jwpat7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129759/302677) to be very useful, although it took me a while to figure out the exact logic needed for this algorithm, so I wrote my [own blog post](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2014/04/20/algorithm-for-drawing-trees/) to simplify the explanation.

Here's the plain-text logic of how you determine the X node positions:

- Start with a [post-order traversal](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/) of the tree
- Assign an initial X value to each node of 0 if it's the first in a set, or `previousSibling + 1` if it's not.

  [image]
- If a node has children, find the desired X value that would center it over its children.

  - If the node is the left-most node, set its X to that value
  - If the node is not the left-most node, set a `Mod` property on the node to `(X - centeredX)` in order to shift all children so they're centered under this node. The last traversal of the tree will use this `Mod` property to determine the final X value of each node.
- Determine if any of this node's children would overlap any children of siblings to the left of this node. Basically for each Y, get the largest and smallest X from the two nodes, and compare them.

  - If any collisions occur, shift the node over by however much needed. Shifting a subtree just requires adding to the `X` and `Mod` properties of the node.
  - If node was shifted, also shift any nodes between the two subtrees that were overlapping so they are equally spaced out
- Do a check to ensure that when the final X is calculated, there is no negative X values. If any are found, add the largest one to the Root Node's `X` and `Mod` properites to shift the entire tree over
- Do a second traversal of the tree using pre-order traversal and add the sum of the `Mod` values from each of a node's parents to it's `X` property

The final X values of the tree above would look like this:

[image]

I have some more details and some sample code in [my blog post](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2014/04/20/algorithm-for-drawing-trees/), but it's too long to include everything here, and I wanted to focus on the logic of the algorithm instead of code specifics.

Comment: Revisiting this problem nearly a decade later... The pseudo code for Walker's generalization of the Reingold-Tilford algorithm may be found at https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/spe.4380200705 ; Besides the easy-to-fix bugs in both the SECONDWALK and the APPORTION functions, the alg. will only require two passes: post- and pre-order. Buchheim's improvement should then transform it to linear time: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-36151-0_32.pdf ; `[mod]ifier` is for the subtree relative-offset and `prelim` is for the node itself. Thought I'd share for others here. :)

Answer (score 4):

A couple of articles are available that include code, in python at [billmill.org](http://billmill.org/pymag-trees/) and in C on [page 2](http://www.drdobbs.com/positioning-nodes-for-general-trees/184402320?pgno=2) of a 1 February 1991 [Dr. Dobb's Journal article](http://www.drdobbs.com/positioning-nodes-for-general-trees/184402320?pgno=4).  You have asked for “simple 2-3 methods” (perhaps meaning cookbook methods) but drawing trees nicely in all their generality is an NP-complete problem (see Supowit, K.J. and E.M. Reingold, "The complexity of drawing trees nicely," Acta Informatica 18, 4, January 1983, 377-392, ref. 4 in the DDJ article).  The  Reingold–Tilford method draws binary trees more or less nicely in linear time, and Buchheim's variation draws n-ary trees more or less nicely in linear time.  However, the billmill article points out (shortly after stating Principle 6),  “Every time so far that we've looked at a simple algorithm in this article, we've found it inadequate...” so the likelihood of simpler methods working ok is small.

Comment: Well, what I meant by 2-3 simple methods was to 'simply' obtain those x-values. I already know it will take many more to properly draw each node to the screen: my first data visualization control was a sunburst control as found here: http://tekuconcept.blogspot.com/2012/10/adjacency-sunburst-diagram-in-c.html ;  I'll read up on the links you've shared just now.