# C# Generate Tree Diagram Node Coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tree, hierarchy

I am trying to draw a tree diagram in Unity3D using c#, I have a list of data which contains the following variables:

```
public class ObjectData
{
    public string ID;
    public string hierarchyParent;
    public int hierarchyLevel;
}
```

The parent variable contains the ID of the parent object and the level variable contains an ascending number of the row ie Top row = 1, Row below = 2 etc. I need to get the coordinates in a 2D space of each node of this tree diagram for an unknown number of items. If I try to create this by setting the rows and adding a constant x value, connection lines often cross and are uncentered. I have looked at some other examples but have not been able to find a tutorial for my input data. Thanks!

Comment: Not a very simple problem. Might work well if your actual trees are relatively small. Your question is more that of an algorithm. Have a look [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128750/what-are-the-step-to-the-reingold-tilford-algorithm-and-how-might-i-program-it) for Reingold-Tilford that supposively solves your requirement "lines often cross and are uncentered" for a few cases, (I assume you want root hierarchial) or if its not try for "SpaceTree" algorithm, theres a lot of other algo's depending on how you want your tree to look

Comment: Would also recommend having a look at the [force-directed graph drawing method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) if you haven't already. It's usually quite easy to implement and can produce good looking results.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Tewr's answer to find this blog post: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2014/04/20/algorithm-for-drawing-trees/

Which fully depicts how to solve my problem!