# Algorithm for drawing a trees where nodes can attach to others with a depth greater than itself + 1

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, canvas, graph-algorithm

This is not a duplicate of the Reingold-tolford, since that's just for drawing normal tree like structures. specifically I am looking for an algorithm where a node can link to a node thats not only on the level below it.

I'm building a tree like structure within a canvas control in WPF.
Currently I have a structure built like this(ignore the collisions of boxes I have that fixed) that generates automatically from my data.

While this structure isn't to bad, it'd be nice to work towards something with less collisions.

Therefore are there any algorithms I can follow and work with to draw a graph like this with less collisions.

I'm calculating all positions of the boxes like this currently,

flattenedList is a List < List< Object>> hence the i, j itteration. and that object has a treePosition Property with an X and Y double.

```
var canvasWidthFinder = new List<int>();
//Loop through all componentversions, use indexes to calc their positions.
for (int i = 0; i < flattenedList.Count; i++)
{
   canvasWidthFinder.Add(flattenedList[i].Count);
   for (int j = 0; j < flattenedList[i].Count; j++)
   {
      flattenedList[i][j].TreePosition.YPosition = (i * 150) + 25;
      flattenedList[i][j].TreePosition.XPosition = ((Canvas.ActualWidth / (flattenedList[i].Count + 1)) * (j + 1)) - (125 / 2);
   }
}
Canvas.Width = (canvasWidthFinder.Max() * 160);
```

These values are then used to draw borders with text inside and lines drawn between the connecting ones.

[image: Tree like graph structure.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the step to the Reingold-Tilford algorithm and how might I program it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128750/what-are-the-step-to-the-reingold-tilford-algorithm-and-how-might-i-program-it)

Answer (score 1):

You could represent links that skip layers by creating dummy items in the intermediate layers. Then when you display the tree you could replace each dummy item with a vertical line instead of a block.

Comment: It's not a bad idea though unfortunately I don't think that will work in this scenario, there are to many possibilities for boxes to be linking to other layers and after looking into it in a large amount of cases it's not helpful, and still collides. I think really this isn't even a tree so much and may not even be possible.