# How to redistribute graph elements to maximize readability?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, rectangles

I have a graph that consists of nodes. Each node can have multiple parents and/or children. I want to display that graph and connections between nodes.

But I don't know how to redistribute nodes to maximize readability. Currently I'm facing following problems:

- Node connections cross each other too much even though it's unnecessary and can be evaded
- Connections between nodes are too long visually
- Some connections have the same angle so they overlap and become one line
- Connections beteween column `i` and column `i-2` (and further away) sometimes go straight through elements in column `i-1`

Also I can shift nodes only vertically, not horizontally because the amount of columns is limited.

To make it easier for myself I tried to place nodes in a grid-like pattern. And I've managed to group them by columns. But then I somehow need to iterate through columns and compare them with other columns to re-arrange stuff. And I don't know where to start.

UPD: I may be wrong but I feel like my problem with graph alignment is somehow related to a typical graph problem of the shortest path. Except that in my case there are multiple paths that should be calculated at the same time and some nodes can be passed only once.

On the image below you can see a nearly ideal redistribution that I made by just scribbling stuff on paper (direction left-to-right shows parent-to-child connections).

[image]

Comment: As discussed [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/14919/73887), drawing a graph with minimum number of edge crossings is an NP-hard problem in general, and it doesn't seem that your constraint (nodes in columns) is going to help. The first step would be to allow curved edges to help with some of the clutter. The resources in the link could help you further understand what you need to do.

Comment: Unfortunately curved edges aren't supported by the app. Other than that, I'll look into links.

Comment: Did you try force-directed layouts? These would minimize overlaps and crossing edges...

Comment: Unfortunately my horizontal space is limited and I can't make a radial force-directed layout, even though it sounds interesting.

Comment: To my mind, this is a really hard problem, basically because it is not clearly defined what the goal is. I would thus try to define a fitness function („how good is the solution“?) that depends on all of your requirements, properly weighted. As soon if you have such a fitness function, you could apply an [Evolutionary Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm) that develops a population of to a local optimum.

Comment: [Vega](https://vega.github.io/vega/) can be another potential source to draw inspiration from, check out how [they do tree layouts](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/master/packages/vega-hierarchy/src/Tree.js). See more information on used algorithm in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128750/what-are-the-step-to-the-reingold-tilford-algorithm-and-how-might-i-program-it)

Comment: how many columns and how many nodes per column? maybe dumb brute force can do?. note that you can have situations where you have to cross edges (K3,3) and such

Comment: Max 10 columns (because horizontal space is limited). Unknown amount of nodes per column. I understand that sometimes if some guy will create a weird perk tree we'll get lines crossing each other, that's fine. As for bruteforce, I feel like it's going to be very slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is graph layout and drawing problem.  You can take one of the following two approaches

1. **Use already existing libraries**: There are many graph layout libraries available for example GraphViz, Gephi, D3js etc. You can use theirs APIs directly or you can find applications/tools build on top of them. But to get best layout, you need to have guess on family of layout. e.g. Layered graph layout (Good for dense but layered graph like flowcharts) Tree layout (Used when graph is actually a tree or forest. There are many variants of tree), Radial tree layout (Again for tree but in polar system), Force directed layouts (When you don't know what visual structure will best represent the data, it is good starting point). All these layout will have many customization parameters like spacing between nodes, spacing between nodes and edges, overall aspect ratio of drawing etc.
   [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/)
   [Gephi](https://gephi.org/)
2. **Implement layout algorithms yourself**
   Detailed coverage of graph drawing algorithms for different families can be found here
   [Graph Drawing Handbook](http://cs.brown.edu/people/rtamassi/gdhandbook/)

If you don't want to get into details, here are quick start points

1. For graphs, Do a topological sort and place nodes in layers as dictated by topo order. It can give you a very good starting point and help you avoid unnecessary crossings. Grid can be good idea here. But place nodes in grid in topo order.
2. Alternatively, Find a spanning tree for the graph, use tree layouts to draw spanning tree and then add remaining edges
3. For trees: Use recursive bottoms up approach for placing subtrees. For radial trees, do rectilinear layout and then transform to polar coordinate system
4. For unknown family: Use force directed method. Define force between two nodes (e.g. spring force) and then go through iterations to find equilibrium point.

Best auto visualization of  a graph is very interesting area and people are trying many ML techniques here.

Comment: My graph is not really a tree because a child can have multiple parents. And on top of that a child on layer 5 can have parent on layer 4 but also on layer 3 or 2. Idk how this type of graph is called.
As for libraries, I need to code this in Lua without C dependencies.

Comment: Topo sort followed by placement in grid as per topo order can good start for your graph. If you want to improve further in terms of crossing minimization then Sugiyama based layered graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing)  approach can be useful

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [force directed drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing). Or you could use a graph drawing library that already supports force directed drawing, such as D3's [force directed layout](https://github.com/d3/d3-force).

[image]

Comment: I can't use radial graphs, I need to make it left to right.

Comment: @user64675 then disable the force and you can arrange elements however you like ‍♂️

Comment: And this would defeat the whole purpose