# how to set coordinates (x,y) for each id inside the tree

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, graph, tree

I have a problem when I try to calculate the position of each ID so I can spread them out on canvas hierarchically.
It can be a tree or many trees (I guess it called forest).
cannot be cycles.
boxes need to be? 240 X 100.

I start from the connections I get: **connectionsArr**.

Inside the function ***graphWithTopLeft*** is the way I calculate the positions for each ID , in my example some of the ID's on top of each other & spacing between them not as I wish for.

In the end I tried to get something like this for all cases:

[image: IMG]

I know these algorithm are nontrivial, but I don't want to use an external library.

Thanks in advance to those who helped and will help.

Code example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-dew-ry5tly?file=/src/index.ts) & also here.

```js
const connectionsArr = [
  { sourceId: 1, targetId: 2 },
  { sourceId: 1, targetId: 3 },
  { sourceId: 1, targetId: 4 },

  { sourceId: 2, targetId: 5 },
  { sourceId: 2, targetId: 6 },
  { sourceId: 2, targetId: 7 },
  { sourceId: 2, targetId: 8 },
  { sourceId: 3, targetId: 10 },
  { sourceId: 3, targetId: 9 },
  { sourceId: 4, targetId: 11 },
  { sourceId: 4, targetId: 12 },
  { sourceId: 11, targetId: 12 },
  { sourceId: 13, targetId: 12 }
];
const WIDTH = 200;

//Find the roots id
function findParents(connections) {
  const parents = [];
  const notParents = [];
  connections.forEach((con1) => {
    const t = connections.filter((cf) => cf.targetId === con1.sourceId);
    t.forEach((t2) => notParents.push(t2.targetId));
  });

  const allIds = connections.map((con) => con.sourceId);
  const arrayWithDuplicate = allIds.filter((val) => !notParents.includes(val));
  arrayWithDuplicate.forEach((a, index) => {
    if (!parents.find((p) => a === p)) {
      parents.push(a);
    }
  });
  return parents;
}
//return arrays of objects (object is like a tree)
function getTrees(flatList) {
  const graph = [];
  flatList.forEach((item) => {
    if (!graph[item.sourceId]) {
      graph[item.sourceId] = {
        id: item.sourceId,
        children: []
      };
    }
    if (!graph[item.targetId]) {
      graph[item.targetId] = {
        id: item.targetId,
        children: []
      };
    }
    graph[item.sourceId].children.push(graph[item.targetId]);
  });
  return graph;
}
//function that return the number of the vertex all the way to the id given
function getAllIds(connections, id) {
  const result = [];
  connections.forEach((connection) => {
    if (connection.sourceId === id) {
      result.push(connection.targetId);
      result.push(...getAllIds(connections, connection.targetId));
    }
  });
  return result;
}
//function that return tree with levels
function updateLevels(trees, level) {
  for (let i = 0; i < trees.length; i++) {
    if (trees[i].children && trees[i].children.length) {
      updateLevels(trees[i].children, level + 1) //next level for children
    }
    trees[i].level = level;
  }
  return trees;
}
//get the max children in the level tree
function getMaxChildren(tree) {
  let max = 0;
  let id = 1;
  const getMax = (node) => {
    if (node.children) {
      if (node.children.length > max) {
        max = node.children.length;
        id = node.id;
      }
      node.children.forEach((child) => {
        getMax(child);
      });
    }
  };
  getMax(tree);
  return { max, id };
}

const parents = findParents(connectionsArr);
// console.log(parents);

const filterArray = getTrees(connectionsArr).filter(
  (f, index) =>
    f.id === parents[0] || f.id === parents[1] || f.id === parents[2]
);

const updated = updateLevels(filterArray, 0);
// console.log( JSON.stringify(updated, null, "   ") );

//get the tree hight
function getDepth(jsonTree) {
  let depth = 0;
  const recurse = (obj, currentDepth) => {
    if (obj.children) {
      depth = Math.max(depth, currentDepth);
      obj.children.forEach((child) => recurse(child, currentDepth + 1));
    }
  };
  recurse(jsonTree, 0);
  return depth;
}

function graphWithTopLeft(
  trees,
  newPositionNodes= [],
  index = 0,
  depth = 0,
  parent = 0
) {
  const findLevel = trees
    .filter((lev) => lev.level === index)
    .sort((a, b) =>
      getAllIds(connectionsArr, a.id).length <
      getAllIds(connectionsArr, b.id).length
        ? 1
        : -1
    );

  findLevel.forEach((node, indexLevel) => {
    if (node.level === 0) {
      const y = 0;
      const x =
        indexLevel === 0
          ? 0
          : indexLevel *
            getAllIds(connectionsArr, findLevel[indexLevel].id).length *
            findLevel.length *
            200;

      newPositionNodes.push({
        id: node.id,
        name: `Node${node.id}`,
        left: x,
        top: y,
        isDragging: false
      });
    }
    if (node.level === 1) {
      const getMaxChildInLevel = getMaxChildren(node);
      const findParent = newPositionNodes.find((f) => f.id === parent);
      const axisX =
        Math.pow(findLevel.length, depth - 1) * getMaxChildInLevel.max;
      const y = node.level * WIDTH;
      const x =
        indexLevel === 0
          ? -(axisX / 3) - (indexLevel * WIDTH + WIDTH)
          : axisX / 3 + indexLevel <= 1
          ? (findParent?.left ) +
            indexLevel *
              WIDTH *
              (node.children.length > 0 ? node.children.length : 1)
          : (newPositionNodes[indexLevel - 1]?.left) +
            indexLevel * WIDTH * node.children.length;

      if (axisX === 0 && indexLevel === 0) {
        if (!newPositionNodes.find((n) => n.id === node.id)) {
          const findParent = newPositionNodes.find((f) => f.id === parent);
          newPositionNodes.push({
            id: node.id,
            name: `Node${node.id}`,
            left: findParent?.left ,
            top: y,
            isDragging: false
          });
        }
      } else if (!newPositionNodes.find((n) => n.id === node.id)) {
        newPositionNodes.push({
          id: node.id,
          name: `Node${node.id}`,
          left: x,
          top: y,
          isDragging: false
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (!newPositionNodes.find((n) => n.id === node.id)) {
        const findParent = newPositionNodes.find((f) => f.id === parent);
        const y = (node.level ) * WIDTH;
        const x =
          indexLevel === 0
            ? (findParent?.left) - WIDTH
            : indexLevel <= 1
            ? (findParent?.left) +
              indexLevel *
                WIDTH *
                (node.children.length > 0 ? node.children.length : 1)
            : (newPositionNodes[indexLevel - 1]?.left) +
              indexLevel * WIDTH * node.children.length;

        if (findLevel.length <= 1) {
          newPositionNodes.push({
            id: node.id,
            name: `Node${node.id}`,
            left: findParent?.left,
            top: y,
            isDragging: false
          });
        } else {
          newPositionNodes.push({
            id: node.id,
            name: `Node${node.id}`,
            left: x,
            top: y,
            isDragging: false
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < trees.length; i++) {
    const depth = getDepth(trees[i]);
    if (trees[i].children && trees[i].children?.length > 0) {
      graphWithTopLeft(
        trees[i].children,
        newPositionNodes,
        index + 1,
        depth,
        trees[i].id
      );
    }
  }

  return newPositionNodes;
}

const display = graphWithTopLeft(updated, [], 0);

console.log(display);

// <------------------------------Canvas------------------------------>

const canvas = document.querySelector("#paper");

const WIDTHcA = canvas.width;
const HEIGHTCA = canvas.height;
// drag related variables
let dragok = false;
let startX;
let startY;


const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTHcA, HEIGHTCA);
}

function drawLine(
  ctx,
  begin,
  end,
  stroke = "black",
  width = 1
) {
  if (stroke) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
  }

  if (width) {
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(begin[0] + 100, begin[1] + 100);
  ctx.lineTo(end[0] + 100, end[1]);
  ctx.stroke();
}

const draw = (t) => {
  clear();
  ctx.translate(600, 100);

  ctx.stroke();
  for (let i = 0; i < display.length; i++) {
    const x = display[i].left;
    const y = display[i].top;
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 200, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";

    ctx.font = "24px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(display[i].name, display[i].left, display[i].top);
  }

  //draw line
  for (let i = 0; i < connectionsArr.length; i++) {
    const sourcePaths = connectionsArr.filter(
      (f) => f.sourceId === connectionsArr[i].sourceId
    );
    const from = display.find((f) => f.id === connectionsArr[i].sourceId);
    sourcePaths.forEach((s) => {
      const to = display.find((f) => f.id === s.targetId);

      if (to && from)
        drawLine(ctx, [from?.left, from?.top], [to.left, to.top], "green", 1);
    });
  }
};

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      body {
        background: black;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="paper" width="10000" height="10000"></canvas>
    <script src="src/index.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You missed to post a specific code you're having issues with. Please read [ask]. [edit] with a [mcve] of a specific problem.

Comment: It's really unclear what "coordinates" you're looking for.  Are you taking about a graph layout algorithm, where `x` and `y` represent pixel positions of boxes?  If so, you will need more specification than this.  Are you talking about where `y` represents the level of the diagram and `x` the position within that level?  What do you mean by "the coordinates will be hierarchical"?  But first, as Roko said, where's your own effort?

Comment: What you’re describing is called a ***tree-drawing algorithm***. [This earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289518/algorithm-for-efficiently-drawing-trees) describes some ways to do this. You’re welcome to code these up yourself if you’d like, but I really do think using an external library is the “correct” way to do this because these algorithms are nontrivial.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'm really sorry it's unclear! my bad
as u said "graph layout algorithm" it's what I need, I'm add right now a link with some code inside what i did already : https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-dew-ry5tly?file=/src/index.ts , I want to put the id's on canvas without using another library that calculate for me the positions , my problem is how to calculate X.
and of course thank you very much for the reference on your part  really appreciate .

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm agreed with u , but I already start do it without using an external library so i want & will finish it

Comment: So looking at that data, you don't have a tree (`4 -> 11`, `4 -> 12`, and `11 -> 12`).  While handling trees *might* be something we could do relatively straightforwardly, I think for general graphs, you will need to read up on [Graph Drawing Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing).

Comment: @ScottSauyet I going to over this "Graph Drawing algorithms" , u said "While handling trees might be something we could do relatively straightforwardly" , if I don't bother u, where I wrong when I calculate the positions?

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse my using an answer for what is really an extended comment.  It's far too long for the comment box.

Here's an answer that seems to meet all the requirements you've given us:

```js
const unique = (xs) => [... new Set (xs)]

const vertices = (edges) => 
  unique (edges .flatMap (({sourceId, targetId}) => [sourceId, targetId])) .sort ((a, b) => a - b)

const coordinates = (edges) =>
  vertices (edges) .map (v => ({id: v, location: {x: 0, y: 0}}))

const connectionsArr = [{sourceId: 1, targetId: 2}, {sourceId: 1, targetId: 9}, {sourceId: 9, targetId: 3}, {sourceId: 3, targetId: 5}, {sourceId: 3, targetId: 7}, {sourceId: 5, targetId: 6}, {sourceId: 6, targetId: 10}, {sourceId: 11, targetId: 12}]

console .log (coordinates (connectionsArr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

For each vertex in the graph, we return an element with `id` and `location` properties, the latter itself containing numeric `x` and `y` properties.  The results look like this:

```js
[
  {id: 1,  location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 2,  location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 3,  location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 5,  location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 6,  location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 7,  location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 9,  location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 10, location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 11, location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 12, location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
]
```

I sense an objection.  The boxes can't all be at the same spot?  Well, why didn't you say so?  We can fix that easily enough.  Just change `coordinates` to

```js
const coordinates = (edges) =>
  vertices (edges) .map ((v, i) => ({id: v, location: {x: i, y: i}}))
```

Now they're in different spots, as we can see with

```js
[
  {id: 1,  location: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 2,  location: {x: 1, y: 1}},
  {id: 3,  location: {x: 2, y: 2}},
  {id: 5,  location: {x: 3, y: 3}},
  {id: 6,  location: {x: 4, y: 4}},
  {id: 7,  location: {x: 5, y: 5}},
  {id: 9,  location: {x: 6, y: 6}},
  {id: 10, location: {x: 7, y: 7}},
  {id: 11, location: {x: 8, y: 8}},
  {id: 12, location: {x: 9, y: 9}},
]
```

Wait, what's that?  They can't overlap?  Well, just make the boxes small enough and they won't overlap.  You can't do that?  Well, why didn't you say any of this?  How big do the boxes need to be?  You don't know?  Ok, we can make it a parameter.  But first, how about if we try with 50 x 50?

Oh, wait, you don't want them in a line?  Ok.  We can fix that too.  Here's another attempt:

```js
const coordinates = (edges) => {
  const vs = vertices (edges)
  const angle = 2 * Math.PI / vs .length
  return vs .map ((v, i) => ({id: v, location: {
    x: Math .round (150 * Math .cos (i * angle)) + 300, 
    y: Math .round (150 * Math .sin (i * angle)) + 300, 
  }}))
}
```

Now they won't overlap at all, giving us something like this:

[image: Picture of ten squares arranged on the border of a circle]

Is this not what you want?  So far each step has met all the requirements given so far.  Perhaps you need better requirements:

- Do you know if your edges form a tree?  A forest?  If it's either, is it a binary tree /forest?
- Or might there be cycles?
- Do you know if your graph is planar?  (That is, it can be drawn on the plane with no edges crossing)
- How do you want your nodes laid out?  A picture of a graph that doesn't even match your code sample is little help.

You need to put more thought into your requirements, and work into your own attempt before we can really help you.

Comment: * Do you know if your edges form a tree? A forest? If it's either, is it a binary tree forest? 
     it can be a tree or many trees (I guess it called forest).

*Or might there be cycles? no cycles 

* How big do the boxes need to be? 240 X 100

*How do you want your nodes laid out?  I added another image.

I really thank you very much for your patience, sometimes I am not as clear as I think

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72794021/edit) your post to include such information.  Also, if your current code is not horrendously long, put it in the question itself.  I for one cannot access codesandbox from work.  I'm sure that's true for others as well.

Comment: I updated the post and attached an example hoping it is clearer.
Thank you for caring :)